# Issues building GridDB CE v4.6 from Source

Tags: database, time-series, griddb

I am currently running GridDB 4.5.2 (from yum) on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009

When attempting to build the new GridDB version from source, I get the following error:

```
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [gsserver-system_service.o] Error 4
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/${USER}/griddb-4.6.0/server'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/${USER}/griddb-4.6.0/server'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is commonly seen when GridDB is compiled on a machine with low memory.